# Print server reprints job

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, print-server

Good afternoon folks,

The pieces to this puzzle are a user machine running win 7 x64 pro which renders the job locally, sends them to a server 2008 r2 print server, which prints them to a HP LaserJet M402dn via IP. We have no permissions/restrictions setup for this specific printer/user.

SNMP is correct and opened on our internal firewall for the specific ports/route.

The issue is printing a tif document that is at least 15 pages long. Have not had any issues on 13 page or less jobs. The job prints, and server looks like it printed, however it stays in the queue and prints every 15 minutes or so. I cleared the queue and its fine now. But can be replicated by printing the job again.

The event log reads as:

> The print job 71 was sent through the print processor hpcpp160 on printer HP m402dn, driver HP Universal Printing PCL 6 (v5.8.0), in the isolation mode 1 (0 - loaded in the spooler, 1 - loaded in shared sandbox, 2 - loaded in isolated sandbox). Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 0x0.
>
> Rendering job 71.
>
> Printing job 71.

Wondering if anyone has come across this issue or has any insight?

Comment: `SNMP is correct and opened on our internal firewall for the specific ports/route.` - SNMP is a network management protocol. It doesn't have anything to do with clinets printing to the printer, with or without a print server. `The job prints, and server looks like it printed, however it stays in the queue and prints every 15 minutes or so` - What do you mean? It prints one page at a time of the 15 page job every 15 minutes or it prints the entire 15 page job every 15 minutes?

Comment: The entire job is printed in a timely matter, all 15 pages no problem. But it will then reprint the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restart printer or machine, if these doesnt work reinstall drivers but first look on printer jobs, might a document stuck.